# Convex solution set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, absolute-value

Let $y, z, a \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true, that the solutions $x \in \mathbb{R}$ of the inequality
$$
\lvert x - y \rvert - \lvert x - z \rvert \leq a
$$
form a convex set (i.e. an interval)? I don't even know if this is true but I have not found a counterexample yet.

I tried to prove this by choosing solutions $x, \tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ and verifying that that $x_t := tx + (1-t)\tilde{x}$ is a solution for $t \in [0, 1]$, too. The latter gave me problems: I tried to add $0 = t\lvert x-y \rvert - t \lvert x -y \rvert + (1-t) \lvert \tilde{x} - z \rvert - (1-t) \lvert \tilde{x} - z \rvert$ and use the reverse triangle inequality but that did not get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $y=z$, then the set $J$ of the inequality solutions is either the emptyset or $\mathbb R$ depending on the sign of $a$. Hence is an interval in that case.

Without loss of generality, you can suppose $y\lt z$ for the rest of the analysis.

Then deal with the three cases $x \le y\lt z$, $y <x \le z$ and $x >z$ to get rid of the absolute values. For each cases, the solution set is the intersection of two intervals. Hence is an interval.

This enables to graph the map $x \mapsto \vert x-y \vert - \vert x-z \vert$ which is constant, then linearly growing then constant. Hence the level sets of this map  are intervals or the emptyset.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think i solved it! Just for clarification purposes: The solution set is either an interval or the emptyset, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think so despite I haven’t gone to the details. To understand what is happening, graphing the map $x \mapsto \vert x-y \vert - \vert x - z \vert $ is interesting. It is constant, then linearly growing then constant again.

Comment: Oh yes that's interesting. But that clearly means that - as a level set of that map - the solution space is convex.

Comment: Yes! And I understood that after writing my answer...